# how to fix "GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_sample_get_buffer: assertion 'GST_IS_SAMPLE (sample)' failed"

Tags: c++, linux, qt, ubuntu, gstreamer

I wanted to grab video frame via gstreamer and display on my app(using Qt) but I encounter some issue:

When I tried to use GstAppSink (gst_app_sink_pull_sample) it keep returning NULL, which I don't understand. I can stream the video using terminal (gst-launch-1.0) perfectly.

Below is my code:

```
void gstreamer::openStream()
{
    pipeline = gst_parse_launch ("rtspsrc location=rtsp://192.168.10.123 ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! queue ! avdec_h264 ! xvimagesink sync=false async=false appsink name=mysink", NULL);

    GstElement* sink = gst_bin_get_by_name(GST_BIN(pipeline), "mysink");

    GstAppSink* appsink = GST_APP_SINK(sink);

    if(!appsink)
    {
        qDebug() << "get app sink failed";
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << "app sink pass";
        mAppSink = appsink;

        openSample();
    }
}

void gstreamer::openSample()
{

    if(!mAppSink)
    {
        qDebug() << "appsink failed";
    }
    GstSample* gstSample = gst_app_sink_pull_sample(mAppSink);

    if(gstSample == NULL)
    {
        qDebug() << "sample failed ";
    }
    else{
        qDebug() << "sample pass";
    }

    GstBuffer* buffer = gst_sample_get_buffer(gstSample);
    if(!buffer)
    {
        qDebug() << "buffer fail";
    }

    GstMapInfo map;

    gst_buffer_map(buffer, &map, GST_MAP_READ);


    QImage image = QImage((map.data), 320, 240, QImage::Format_RGB888);
    emit sendFrame(image);
}
```

I tried to find in the web but there is hardly any links for this issue.

Comment: `xvimagesink sync=false async=false appsink name=mysink` this part does not make sense. You want the xvimagesink or the appsink. Both with this syntax is just gibberish.

Comment: Hi I just want appsink, was just testing with xvimagesink to see whats the different.

Comment: Also you are not even starting the pipeline. And you probably should hook into a callback whenever a new sample is available too. I suggest to read some of the appsink examples of Gstreamer.

Comment: If i set gst_element_set_state, then the stream will come out but I wont be able to display it on my app. My idea is to grab the frame and display on my app instead of one window by itself.

Comment: Its too long to explain here. You should look at the `GstVideoOverlay` examples. It allows you to do exactly that - rendering a video inside your own app's widgets instead of its own window.

Comment: Ok, I will go and take a look! Thanks so much!

Answer (score -1):

Try changing the pipeline to
"rtspsrc location=rtsp://192.168.10.123 ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! tee name=my_tee ! queue ! avdec_h264 ! xvimagesink sync=false my_tee. ! queue! appsink  async=false name=mysink"